# Left join is not returning all rows from other table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
SELECT paybacks.id as payback_id, paybacks.booking_id, bookings.status, paybacks.success, bookings.id as booking_id FROM `bookings` LEFT JOIN `paybacks` ON `paybacks`.`booking_id` = `bookings`.`id` WHERE (bookings.status = 1) AND (paybacks.success = true)
```

In Rails

```
Booking.where("bookings.status = 1").joins("LEFT JOIN `paybacks` ON `paybacks`.`booking_id` = `bookings`.`id`").select("paybacks.points_to_redeem as payback_points_used").where("paybacks.success = true" ).select("bookings.id as booking_id")
```

I have 1659 rows in booking table but getting only 800 rows. Please help me for this.

Comment: change `paybacks.success = true` to `paybacks.success = true or paybacks.success is null`

Comment: no this is not working and giving me results more than the expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the second `where` condition to the on condition:

```
SELECT paybacks.id as payback_id, paybacks.booking_id, bookings.status, paybacks.success, bookings.id as booking_id FROM `bookings` LEFT JOIN `paybacks` ON `paybacks`.`booking_id` = `bookings`.`id` AND (paybacks.success = true)
 WHERE (bookings.status = 1)
```

If you do not do it, all records in `bookings` wich have no record in `paybacks` will be ignored.

Input:

booking:

```
ID |  attribute1 | attribute2
1  | xxx         | yyyy
2  | yyy         | zzzz
```

paybacks:

```
ID |  bookings_id | success
1  |  1           | true
```

After left join you have this:

```
booking.ID | attribute1 |attribute2 | paybacks.ID | bookung_id | success
1          | xxx        | yyyy      |  1          |  1         | true
2          | yyy        | zzzz      |  null       |  null      | null
```

And if you have the `success = true` in your where statement you will ignore the second line, because

```
success is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets illustrate this with an example. 
When we do left join with where condition it will filter the records after the join.

Lets say we have 2 tables

```
mysql> select * from test1;
+------+------+--------+
| id   | val  | status |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 | a    |      0 |
|    2 | b    |      1 |
|    3 | c    |      1 |
|    4 | d    |      1 |
|    5 | d    |      0 |
+------+------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test2 ;
+------+------+------+
| id   | t1id | val  |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 | aaa  |
|    2 |    2 | aaa  |
|    3 |    3 | aaa  |
|    4 |    5 | eeee |
+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If we need to get all the data from test1 and by doing a `left join` to test2, it will return all the data from test1 and non matching record from test2 as null

```
select t1.*,
t2.t1id from 
test1 t1 left join test2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1id ;



 +------+------+--------+------+
| id   | val  | status | t1id |
+------+------+--------+------+
|    1 | a    |      0 |    1 |
|    2 | b    |      1 |    2 |
|    3 | c    |      1 |    3 |
|    4 | d    |      1 | NULL |
|    5 | d    |      0 |    5 |
+------+------+--------+------+
```

Now if we add where condition it will filter the data after the join as

```
select t1.*,
t2.t1id 
from test1 t1 
left join test2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1id  where t1.status = 1;


+------+------+--------+------+
| id   | val  | status | t1id |
+------+------+--------+------+
|    2 | b    |      1 |    2 |
|    3 | c    |      1 |    3 |
|    4 | d    |      1 | NULL |
+------+------+--------+------+
```

Or even

```
select t1.*,
 t2.t1id from test1 t1 
 left join test2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1id  
 where t2.val = 'aaa'

+------+------+--------+------+
| id   | val  | status | t1id |
+------+------+--------+------+
|    1 | a    |      0 |    1 |
|    2 | b    |      1 |    2 |
|    3 | c    |      1 |    3 |
+------+------+--------+------+
```

Now if we want the left table data to be displayed then we need to move the where condition into the joining condition, in the result the non-matching records will be shown as null.

```
select t1.*,
t2.t1id from test1 t1 
left join test2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1id 
and t1.status = 1 and  t2.val = 'aaa'

+------+------+--------+------+
| id   | val  | status | t1id |
+------+------+--------+------+
|    1 | a    |      0 | NULL |
|    2 | b    |      1 |    2 |
|    3 | c    |      1 |    3 |
|    4 | d    |      1 | NULL |
|    5 | d    |      0 | NULL |
+------+------+--------+------+
```

So in your case you have to move the where condition into the joining condition if you want all the records from the left table to be there in the result.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. Please check the below query. I add `and` with `join` conditions. It is giving me the exact answer.

```
SELECT bookings.id as booking_id, paybacks.points_to_redeem as payback_points_used FROM `bookings` LEFT JOIN `paybacks` ON `paybacks`.`booking_id` = `bookings`.`id` and paybacks.success = true WHERE (bookings.status = 1) GROUP BY paybacks.booking_id
```